# Delphi JEDI: DHCPEnumSubnets returns garbage information

Tags: delphi

I'm trying to use the dhspsapi function DHCPEnumSubnets, to list all the available subnets on an office DHCP server. For security sake, all IP addresses have been modified from the actual ones used in our corporate environment, to addresses in the 192.168.0.1/24 network.
Since I'm writing in Borland Delphi 7, the library I used for this task was Delphi JEDI, specifically the JwaDhcpsApi unit.
In JWADhcpApi.pas, DHCPEnumSubnets is declared like this:

```
type
DHCP_RESUME_HANDLE = DWORD;
_DHCP_IP_ARRAY = record
    NumElements: DWORD;
    Elements: LPDHCP_IP_ADDRESS; //array
  end;
{$EXTERNALSYM _DHCP_IP_ARRAY}
DHCP_IP_ARRAY = _DHCP_IP_ARRAY;
{$EXTERNALSYM DHCP_IP_ARRAY}
LPDHCP_IP_ARRAY = ^DHCP_IP_ARRAY;
{$EXTERNALSYM LPDHCP_IP_ARRAY}
LPPDHCP_IP_ARRAY = ^LPDHCP_IP_ARRAY;
...

function DhcpEnumSubnets(ServerIpAddress: PWideChar; var ResumeHandle: DHCP_RESUME_HANDLE; PreferredMaximum: DWORD; EnumInfo: LPDHCP_IP_ARRAY; out ElementsRead, ElementsTotal: DWORD): DWORD; stdcall;
```

So EnumInfo holds a pointer to a DHCP_IP_ARRAY structure, which is a record containing a field holding the total number of subnets and another field containing a pointer to an array of DWORD.
According to MSDN, the subnet IDs are DWORD values holding the bits of the subnet IP address in binary form.

This is the Delphi code I use for reading subnets from the DHCP server. There is only one subnet on that particular server, so no need to loop DHCPEnumSubnets and wait for ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS.

```
unit Main;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, JwaDhcpsApi, StdCtrls, Math;

type
  TfmMain = class(TForm)
    Memo1: TMemo;
    Button1: TButton;
    Button2: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    function IpAddressToId(const Address: string): Cardinal;
    function IdToIpAddress(const Id: Cardinal):string;
    procedure Trace(const S: string);
  public
    procedure PrintMemory(const P: Pointer; const Text: string; const Bytes: integer);
    function FindIp(const Value: string; const Address: Pointer; Length: integer): Cardinal;
  end;

var
  fmMain: TfmMain;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TfmMain.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  ServerIpAddress: WideString;
  PServerIPAddress: PWidechar;
  ResumeHandle: DHCP_RESUME_HANDLE;
  PreferredMaximum: Cardinal;
  ElementsRead: Cardinal;
  ElementsTotal: Cardinal;
  Error: Cardinal;
  i: Cardinal;
  ElementPointer: LPDHCP_IP_ADDRESS;
  subnet: DWORD;
  EnumInfo: LPDHCP_IP_ARRAY;
  NumElements: DWORD;
  ArrayAddress: Cardinal;

begin
  ServerIPAddress:='192.168.0.238';
  PServerIPAddress:=PWideChar(ServerIPAddress);
  PreferredMaximum:=65536;
  GetMem(EnumInfo,SizeOf(Pointer));
  GetMem(EnumInfo^.Elements,10000);
  ElementsRead:=0;
  ElementsTotal:=0;
  ResumeHandle:=0;
  try  
 
  try
    Error:=DhcpEnumSubnets(PServerIPAddress,ResumeHandle,PreferredMaximum,EnumInfo,ElementsRead,ElementsTotal);
    if Error <> ERROR_SUCCESS then
      begin
        Trace('Error reading subnets from DHCP server');
        Exit;
      end; 
    //NumElements:=EnumInfo^.NumElements;  DOES NOT WORK !!!
    NumElements:=PDWORD(EnumInfo^.NumElements)^;
    Trace('NumElements = ' + IntToStr(NumElements));
    Trace('DhcpEnumSubnets returned ' + IntToStr(Error));
    Trace('ElementsRead = ' + IntToStr(ElementsRead));
    ArrayAddress:=Cardinal(EnumInfo^.Elements);
    for i:=0 to NumElements - 1 do begin
      New(ElementPointer);
      ElementPointer:=LPDHCP_IP_ADDRESS(ArrayAddress + i*SizeOf(Pointer));
      subnet:=ElementPointer^;
      Trace('subnet['+IntToStr(i)+'] = ' + IntToStr(subnet) + ' ; IP = ' + IdToIpAddress(subnet));
    end;
  finally
    DHCPRpcFreeMemory(EnumInfo);
  end;
end;

function TfmMain.FindIp(const Value: string;
  const Address: Pointer; Length: integer): Cardinal;
var
  i: Cardinal;
  subnet: Cardinal;
begin
  Result:=0;
  if (Value = '') or (Address = nil) or (Length <=0) then Exit;
  subnet:=IpAddressToId(Value);
  for i:=0 to Length - 1 do
    begin
      Trace(IntToStr(i) + ' : ' + IdToIpAddress(PDWORD(Cardinal(Address) + i*SizeOf(Pointer))^));
      if PDWORD(Cardinal(Address) + i)^ = subnet then
         begin
           Result:=Cardinal(Address) + i;
           Break;
         end;
    end;
end;

function TfmMain.IdToIpAddress(const Id: Cardinal): string;
var
  b1,b2,b3,b4: Cardinal;
begin
  Result:='';
  if Id > Power(2,32) then Exit;
  b1:=Id and 255;
  b2:=(Id and 65280) shr 8;
  b3:=(Id and 16711680) shr 16;
  b4:=(Id and 4278190080) shr 24;
  Result:=IntToStr(b4) + '.' + IntToStr(b3) + '.' + IntToStr(b2) + '.' + IntToStr(b1);
end;

function TfmMain.IpAddressToId(const Address: string): Cardinal;
var
  S: string;
  b1,b2,b3,b4: integer;
  p: integer;
begin
  Result:=0;
  if Address = '' then Exit;
  S:=Address;
  try
    p:=Pos('.',S);
    b1:=StrToInt(Copy(S,1,P-1));
    Delete(S,1,P);
    p:=Pos('.',S);
    b2:=StrToInt(Copy(S,1,P-1));
    Delete(S,1,P);
    p:=Pos('.',S);
    b3:=StrToInt(Copy(S,1,P-1));
    Delete(S,1,P);
    b4:=StrToInt(S);
    Result:= 16777216*b1 + 65536*b2 + 256*b3 + b4;
  except
  end;
end;

procedure TfmMain.PrintMemory(const P: Pointer; const Text: string; const Bytes: integer);
var
  i: integer;
  address: integer;
  L: integer;
  S: string;
begin
  if P = nil then Exit;
  L:=Length(Text);
  for i:=0 to Bytes - 1 do
    begin
      address:=Integer(P) + i;
      S:=PWideChar(address);
      if Text = '' then Trace(IntToStr(i) + ' : ' + S)
      else if Copy(S,1,L) = Text then Trace(IntToStr(i) + ' : ' + S);
    end;
end;

procedure TfmMain.Trace(const S: string);
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Add(S);
end;

end.
```

The code compiles and runs, but it does not return the correct values from DHCP.

1. According to MSDN, EnumSubnets.NumElements should contain the number of subnets enumerated by DHCPEnumSubnets. In fact it contains some huge number, while the actual number of subnets is 1. That number was suspiciously resembling a memory address, so I decided to read it as a pointer to DWORD. And that actually gave the correct value: 1.
2. DHCP subnet is 192.168.0.192. The subnet Id read from EnumInfo.Elements was 4535816 which translates to an IP "address" of 0.69.54.8

I wrote the function SearchIP, and tried reading the memory allocated to EnumInfo directly and search for a DWORD value equivalent to 192.168.0.192, but no luck.

The PC I'm running the program on is Windows 10. I also tried running it on the server itself, with the same result.

Please give me some advice on how to approach this problem.
Could this be an issue with JEDI API in a 64-bit environment?

UPDATE: I have imported the functions directly from dhcpsapi.dll, with the same result. So this has nothing to do with Delphi JEDI, it's either an issue with the Delphi compiler, or with the dll itself.

Comment: What does your 32-bit test result say?

Comment: @SertacAkyuz I ran the application in compatibility mode with Windows 7, Windows XP and Windows 95. Same result...

Comment: You're not checking ERROR to see if it succeeded..

Comment: @FredS sorry I forgot to mention. There is a line of code which prints the ERROR in TMemo, the error is always ERROR_SUCCESS. I will put a proper check for this in the code also.

Comment: Indeed, my test failed with access denied. Need to test as a DHCP admin...

Comment: @SertacAkyuz, I have full admin rights on that server, so in my case that is not the cause of the issue. The code is now checking the error value directly, it's always 0.

Comment: This fails with some OS error against my router DHCP, so no way to test at the moment. Pretty sure EnumInfo memory is allocated by the API therefore the cleanup call.

Comment: @FredS I think dhcpsapi.dll can only query MS DHCP server.

Comment: Also as I read this the pointer going in should be LPPDHCP_IP_ARRAY a Pointer to the Pointer which will be allocated by the API.

Comment: @FredS Quite true. I've tried declaring the function with LPPDHCP_IP_ARRAY type, but this caused an access violation.

Comment: Get rid of the two "GetMem"s.  Reinstate the "NumElements :=" line - the one commented as "does not work", remove the second. Change the API declaration (the jedi one) such that the "EnumInfo" is itself a pointer - that is  ".. var EnumInfo: LPDHCP_IP_ARRAY; ..." .

Comment: @FredS please post your reply in which you mentioned LPPDHCP_IP_ARRAY as the answer. It is the correct answer! I used this type, and the function works properly.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz, thank you for your link on memory deallocation. I have already changed the API declaration as per the advice of FredS, using LPPDHCP_IP_ARRAY instead of LPDHCP_IP_ARRAY, and the function is working correctly. I have tried this before but ran into an access violation which was due to another error, and discarded that solution, which was a mistake. I would also like to add that removing the second GetMem results in an IP address of '0.0.0.1', and removing both of them results in the function returning error code 1780.

Comment: Best would be to post your complete working code as the solution. That will help others..

Comment: @bill - The function does not use the memory you allocated, EnumInfo is an "out" parameter. ...  I removed my comment about releasing the memory, there's no indication that DHCPRpcFreeMemory is not doing it.